in wxmaxima how can i put one picture from wxdraw3d inside another one from plot3d
I like the 3d plot figure : (load(implicit_plot),plot3d( 1,[theta, 0, %pi], [phi, 0, 2*%pi], same_xyz, [transform_xy, spherical_to_xyz],[grid,20,20],[color,black],palette,[png_file, "transform.png"] ));
And i want to put another which i can only do in wxdraw3d: wxdraw(terminal='png,file_name="dashes5",gr2d(fill_color=grey77,color=gray20,line_width=2,ellipse(0,0,1,.5,180,180), line_type=dashes, ellipse(0,0,1,.5,0,180),  proportional_axes='xy))

and i want to put the latter inside the former which will look something like this:
which i did manually in ifranview. As you can see it is not properly done with evenly spaced dashes as desired. I only have basic miktex and can't add anymore packages to it. And can't do it with basic tex picture environment. So if possible how can i do it in wxmaxima ?

Why do you tag it gnuplot? I know wxMaxima uses gnuplot for plotting, but it doesn't sound like you want a gnuplot script to create the desired output. So, gnuplot would not be relevant here. What is actually your final goal? Creating this graph either with wxMaxima or gnuplot for including it into a (La)TeX document?

ok i will take it off there if possible. It always has that word written in maxima help is the reason. I don't really know what it means. Yea i want to put in a basic miktex tex paper.

It would also be ok if that embedded gray looks like an ellipse from the 3d angle were borderless. Maybe even better that way. That picture i included was not the actual output of wxmaxima but i manually drew it in ifran view and would rather not have to do that.

Why isn't that same         plot3d(1,[theta, 0, %pi], [phi, 0, 2*%pi], same_xyz, [transform_xy, spherical_to_xyz] ,[grid,20,20],[color,black],palette )        function available in draw. I know there is a close one in gr3d  or wxdraw3d being                       'spherical(1,a,0,2*%pi,z,0,%pi) ,'  By the way does anyone know how one can make his own transform to use in wxdraw3d or gr3d ?

Tried some things and found a couple ways to approximate it.
wxdraw(terminal='png,file_name="par",gr3d(axis_3d=false,border=false,line_width=6,color=gray82
,view=[111,0],implicit(1.04x^2+1.2y^2+9921z^2-1,x,-1,1,y,-1,1,z,-1,1)
,line_width=.3,color=black,makelist(parametric(sin(t)cos(%pip/8),sin(t)sin(%pip/8),cos(t),t,0,%pi+.1),p,0,8),makelist(parametric( sin(t%pi/16)cos(p),sin(t%pi/16)sin(p),cos(t%pi/16),p,0,%pi),t,0,13) ,proportional_axes='xyz))
Extending the above makelists of paramaterizations and possibly making use of nested makelists and of course arbitrary functions of the parameters one should be able to do all in wxdraw2d for about anything without having to go to 3d.

and    wxdraw(terminal='png,file_name="multi",gr3d(axis_3d=false,border=false,line_width=15,color=gray80,view=[66,0],implicit(1.2x^2+2y^2+9921z^2-1,x,-1,1,y,-1,1,z,-1,1),line_width=.5,color=black,xu_grid=12,yv_grid = 16,spherical(1,a,%pi-.1,2%pi+.21,z,0,%pi),proportional_axes='xyz));

If really wanted to could probably find a way to make dotted lines on the rear end or can do that in tex along with a better way to make the axis/dimensions text annotations etc. than wxmaxima wxdraw does.
